How to use action matching for images (actual images, not URLs or filenames) in KDE Clipboard?
What one does use to match objects such as images?


It will not take images, it expects a regular expression.

Do you know that or is it just your guess? I was going to report this as a bug anyway (or rather a missing feature).

I know this because the klipper documentation on Actions says so (https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/plasma-workspace/klipper/actions.html). Secondly, regular expressions are for text based searches only. Thirdly, the Klipper userbase wiki (https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper) mentions it is for copy / pasting text, not images.

Well, I believe modern Plasma does not use Klipper as there is no mention of that. The widget is called Clipboard and although it seems to be based on Klipper code, it has been further improved and built upon. As for copy/pasting text only (I think you only mean Action here), that might be, that's why > feature request/bug report. But I think MIME actions could be the way, although poorly documented.

While i dont use KDE anymore and am not certain about the current clipboard, the screenshot you pasted sure reminds me alot of Klipper :) Couple that with the fact it actually mentions being Klipper in the first paragraph of the Action Properties window as well as only mentioning regex as input, i'm very confident in my assessment this does not match against images.

That might be, I am not sure uncertain whether some widgets in Plasma were originally programs such as Klipper. I think really Clipboard widget is just Klipper under hood, maybe somehow improved.
